# Pymodbus not finding 'grouped' addresses on device

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I am working on a project in which I'm using Pymodbus to connect to an industrial fan system. I am able to read some addresses on this fan, but not others. The fan's instruction booklet I am working with puts the addresses into "parameter groups", as follows:

| Grouping | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Group 00 | Basic parameters |
| Group 01 | V/F pattern selections and setup |
| Group 02 | Motor parameters |
| Group 03 | Multi function digital Inputs/Outputs |
| ... |  |
| Group 15 | PLC monitoring function |

For each grouping (1-15) above, there are then more specific addresses provided in later pages of the manual. For example, for Group 00, above, there are address entries specified as below:

| Group-address | Description | Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00-00 | Control Mode Selection | 0: V/F Mode, 1: Vector mode |
| 00-02 | Main run command. | 0: Keypad, 1:Communication, 2: PLC |
| ... |  |  |
| 00-20. | Jog deceleration time. | ~0.1-3600.0 |

I am able to access and print the above addresses (for the case of the grouping of '00') with the following Python script:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient    
modbus_conn = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port="/dev/tty.usbserial-AQ00BYCR",baudrate=38400,parity = 'O')
modbus_conn.connect()
print(modbus_conn.read_holding_registers(0,20,unit=1).registers[0])
```

The problem, however, is that I cannot access the higher groupings ('01' -> '15'). For example, if I try to access any address higher than 20 with the above script, I get a "no registers there" error. I'm assuming this is because I am locked into sampling the first grouping ('00') with my script.

I explored the idea that groupings specify different address starting points, so I tested to see whether '01', for example, meant an address starting at the location of '100', as below:

```
modbus_conn.read_holding_registers(100,5,unit=1).registers[0]
```

but this turned out not to work (since I again got 'no register exists there' errors).

What am I doing wrong?

What am I missing?

Does anyone out there know how to access addresses that are grouped in the above way? This is the first time I've seen this, and I am stumped.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the documentation of the device?

Comment: From [this manual](https://my.motovario.com/file.php?s=88qs) (assuming that is the device you are accessing) it looks like group 01 starts at register `0100H` (as opposed 100 decimal); so give `modbus_conn.read_holding_registers(0x100,1,unit=1).registers[0]` a go.

Comment: Thank you this is potentially really useful! And yes, you have identified the correct manual! What does 0x100 actually mean? And what in the instruction manual allows you to conclude that the register starts at 0100H - why the H?

Comment: Its [Hexadecimal](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) - difficult to explain in a comment so simplest to read the wikipedia link. [In python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) an Integer literal that starts with 0x is hex (so 100H is written as 0x100 in python - the H in the docs is just another way of flagging that its hex).

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't realise that 0x was code for hex notation start. This explanation looks intuitively right - I will test it out tomorrow and confirm, then you can make it an official answer so I can award your bounty!

Comment: Hopefully that works for you - note that pages 'App3-13' to 'App3-18' in the manual contain the mapping from the group/function to the Modbus register number (in hex).

Comment: @Brits - thank you - your instruction manual and explanation pulled me out of the fire! If you make your explanation an official answer I will award you the bounty :) Incidentally - the instruction manual that came with the device is out of date and contained no appendix with mappings like the one you provided. So, thank you, life saver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments the first issue was that the manual you were using was out of date. By searching for `"V/F pattern selections and setup"` I located an [updated manual](https://my.motovario.com/file.php?s=88qs). This updated manual included a table that linked the 'groupings' to registers (pages 'App3-13' to 'App3-18'). For example function `01-0`(part of group 01) 'Volts/Hz Patterns' is in holding register 0100H (100 hex).

With the updated manual it is easier to determine how to map from grouping/function to the appropriate register. One potential issue is that the manual refers to the registers in hex (`100H`) so when querying in Python you need to use something like `modbus_conn.read_holding_registers(0x100,1,unit=1).registers[0]` (this probably explains why your initial attempt failed).

*note: when posting this kind of question the more details you can provide the better e.g. device manufacturer, model etc).*

Answer (score 2):

There might be a scheme like below in the documentation of the device:

Address GGnnH: GG means parameter group, nn means parameter number, for example, the address of Pr 04-01 is 0401H. (The 'H' means that the number, 401 in this example, is hexadecimal. Thus 0401H is register 1025)

Comment: Thanks I will check this out and revert asap!

Answer (score 0):

Classifying it as **groupings** for me is very confusing.

To read holding registers you have to pass the offset of the first one and how many you want to read, that's all.

Perhaps the device has no more than 20 readable registers, so if you pass an offset of 10 with a quantity of 20 then you are trying to read up to the 30th register which may not exist.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what was happening. I have realised there were 2 problems - 1. the instruction manual contained no mappings, 2. The addresses were in Hex. Now that I've been lead to the mappings, all is working.